# how to delete listview items

Tags: android

Hi i want to check all listview items and to delete those items from database as well as from the listview.If all listview items are selected and any only one of the listitem is unchecked then the checked items have to be deleted.For this iam using menu's.How can i implement like this? Iam using the below code:

```
public void PopulateSentList() {
        String strquery = "SELECT * FROM sent_history";
        Cursor Cursor = (MainscreenActivity.JEEMAAndroSMSDB).rawQuery(strquery,
                null);
        MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(SentHistoryActivity.this, Cursor);
        setListAdapter(adapter);        
        lvhistory.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                    int position, long arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                SQLiteCursor selectedValue = (SQLiteCursor) getListAdapter()
                        .getItem(position);
                String id1 = selectedValue.getString(0);
                System.out.println("DATA-->>>" + id1);
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        Historydisplay.class);
                intent.putExtra("Id", id1);
                final int result = 1;
                startActivityForResult(intent, result);
            }
        });
    }

    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
        Intent intent = new Intent(SentHistoryActivity.this,
                MainscreenActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }

    private void CreateMenu(Menu menu) {
        menu.setQwertyMode(true);
        MenuItem mnu1 = menu.add(0, 0, 0, "Delete");
        {
            mnu1.setAlphabeticShortcut('a');
        }
        MenuItem mnu2 = menu.add(1, 1, 1, "Select All");
        {
            mnu2.setAlphabeticShortcut('s');
        }
    }

    private boolean MenuChoice(MenuItem item) throws Exception {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case 0:         
            if (getStrinValue != null) {
                delhistory(getStrinValue);
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Please select an Item", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }           
        case 1:
            if(item.getTitle().equals("Select All")){
                for(int i=0; i < lvhistory.getChildCount(); i++){
                    RelativeLayout itemLayout = (RelativeLayout)lvhistory.getChildAt(i);
                    final CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)itemLayout.findViewById(R.id.check);
                    cb.setChecked(true);           
                    if (cb.isChecked() == true) {                               
                        getStrinValue = getStrinValue + ","
                                + cb.getTag().toString();
                    }
                    cb.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {                       
                        @Override
                        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton arg0, boolean arg1) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub          
                            final long[] checkedIds = lvhistory.getCheckItemIds();
                            for (int i = 0; i < checkedIds.length; i++) {
                                Log.e("checkedIds", "id checked: " + checkedIds[i]);
                            }
                            }                       
                    });                 
                }               
            }

        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
        CreateMenu(menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        try {
            return MenuChoice(item);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return false;
    }

    private class MyAdapter extends ResourceCursorAdapter {

        public MyAdapter(Context context, Cursor cur) {
            super(context, R.layout.dummy, cur);
        }

        @Override
        public View newView(Context context, Cursor cur, ViewGroup parent) {
            LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            return li.inflate(R.layout.dummy, parent, false);
        }

        @Override
        public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cur) {
            TextView tvListText = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.Mobile);
            chkBox = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.check);          
            tvListText.setText(cur.getString(cur
                    .getColumnIndex(MainscreenActivity.COL_Mobile)));
            chkBox.setTag(cur.getString(cur
                    .getColumnIndex(MainscreenActivity.COL_Sent_id)));

            chkBox.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) v;
                    if (cb.isChecked() == true) {
                        getStrinValue = getStrinValue + ","
                                + cb.getTag().toString();
                    } else {
                        getStrinValue = null;
                    }
                }
            });
        }   

    }


    public void delhistory(String getStrinValue) {
        int pos1 = getStrinValue.indexOf(",");
        if (pos1 > 0) {
            String rowId = getStrinValue.substring(pos1 + 1);
            String delimiter = "\\,";
            String[] sentID = rowId.split(delimiter);
            for (int i = 0; i < sentID.length; i++) {
                String temp0 = sentID[i];
                int id = Integer.parseInt(temp0);
                MainscreenActivity.JEEMAAndroSMSDB
                        .delete(MainscreenActivity.Table_SentHistory, "_id="
                                + id, null);                
            }
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "History deleted successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
            finish();
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                    SentHistoryActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

you just need to call remove method on adapter, like below

```
   adapter.remove(list.get(i));
```

Dont forget to invalidate it so that  it affects list too.

```
adapter.notifyDatasetChanged()
```

Edit :-  as par user370305 you should calll above method for invalidate it...

Comment: It's `adapter.notifyDatasetChanged()` .

Comment: Thanks, I was just not getting the name of method. Edited my answer.. :)

Answer (score 0):

**Try This Code:-**

**Main.Xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <EditText 
        android:id="@+id/txtItem"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:hint="@string/hintTxtItem"         
        />

    <Button 
        android:id="@+id/btnAdd"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/lblBtnAdd"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/txtItem"
        />

    <TextView 
        android:id="@android:id/empty"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/txtItem"
        android:text="@string/txtEmpty"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"        
        />

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"        
        android:layout_below="@id/txtItem"
        android:choiceMode="multipleChoice" >
    </ListView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnDel"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"        
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:text="@string/lblBtnDel" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

    /** Items entered by the user is stored in this ArrayList variable */
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

    /** Declaring an ArrayAdapter to set items to ListView */
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;


    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        /** Setting a custom layout for the list activity */
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        /** Reference to the add button of the layout main.xml */
        Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAdd);

        /** Reference to the delete button of the layout main.xml */
        Button btnDel = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnDel);

        /** Defining the ArrayAdapter to set items to ListView */
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, list);

        /** Defining a click event listener for the button "Add" */
        OnClickListener listener = new OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                                EditText edit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtItem);
                                list.add(edit.getText().toString());
                                edit.setText("");
                                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        }
                };

        /** Defining a click event listener for the button "Delete" */
        OnClickListener listenerDel = new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                /** Getting the checked items from the listview */
                SparseBooleanArray checkedItemPositions = getListView().getCheckedItemPositions();
                int itemCount = getListView().getCount();

                for(int i=itemCount-1; i >= 0; i--){
                    if(checkedItemPositions.get(i)){                        
                        adapter.remove(list.get(i));
                    }
                }               
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();             
            }
        };            

        /** Setting the event listener for the add button */
        btn.setOnClickListener(listener);

        /** Setting the event listener for the delete button */
        btnDel.setOnClickListener(listenerDel);    

        /** Setting the adapter to the ListView */
        setListAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You must have delete object from db using db's queries and then you should create new adapter or using remove() method to old list adapter